# Can't connect to Windows 10 VM on Azure after installing update

Tags: virtual-machine, remote-desktop, azure, windows-10-preview

I have a Windows 10 VM on Azure, to which I connect using remote desktop. Today I installed the latest preview build on it, and now I can no longer connect using RDP: my credentials no longer work, and I don't have any others.

What can I do to regain access to my VM?

Comment: Have you tried a forced restart?

Comment: @Ramhound, yes, it didn't change anything

Comment: It sounds like your only choice is to rebuild the virtual machine.  It sounds like something happen with the update.  This is to be expect with pre-beta software.

Comment: @Ramhound, in this case, it's probably what I'm going to do, because I don't have anything important on that machine. But what if it happens on a VM where I have critical data and/or applications? There must be a way to access it when RDP isn't working, right?

Comment: That would be a question for Microsoft.  If you have critical data you might want to keep backups of said virtual machine.  I am sure Azure has some mechanic that can make that process easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to access it again by resetting the password using Azure Powershell:

```
Get-AzureVM -ServiceName “xxx”-Name “xxx” | Set-AzureVMAccessExtension -UserName xxx -Password xxx | Update-AzureVM
```

Comment: I've reseted the password with your script, and it says OperationStatus = Succeeded, but still no way to log on to the server.