# Can't connect to Azure VM Windows 10 after upgrading build

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, azure

I have a Windows 10 VM in Azure. I tried to install the latest Windows 10 Preview Build using an ISO from my MSDN account. I was able to mount the ISO and the install seemed to work fine, then the machine needed to restart - and now I cannot connect.

I think I know why this is happening, but I don't know how to fix it. The OS was re-installed so I am guessing my credentials no longer work to RDP. I followed the [troubleshooting steps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-troubleshoot-rdp-connection/#fix-common-remote-desktop-errors) to reset the VMAccessExtension, but the command keeps failing. I have tried both variations. Here is the error I get:

[image]

I do what it says and check my Extensions on my VM and it basically seems that they aren't available since Windows hasn't finished re-installing. I can go to the Boot Diagnostics page, and see that it is stuck on the setup screen after restart:

[image]

I have also tried redeploying the VM and trying to upgrade the OS, and I got the same results. I tried deleting the VM and creating a new one, and get the same results.

Is Azure just not going to allow me to re-install Windows in this manner, or am I missing something?

Edit: Yes, I have looked at [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/840116/cant-connect-to-windows-10-vm-on-azure-after-installing-update) and the command in that answer will not work for me since I am using the new Azure Resource Manager model to set up the VM. But the commands that I am trying in Powershell are the new equivalent.

Comment: Did you ever get a solution for this?

Comment: I ended up using hyper V on my local system. You can go this route and get the vhd file and then create your VM in Azure using a custom vhd and upload the one you made with hyper v. There are a few tutorials out there that will walk you through it. Sorry I don't have them from memory.

Answer (score 0):

The Azure images are using Windows 10 Enterprise N (N means there's no multimedia enhancements like Media Player). If you try to update to the **non-N** version, you'll get an install prompt when the setup restarts and you won't be able to get further on Azure.

If you update using the "Windows 10 Enterprise **N** x64 en-us", and keep all the setup defaults, you'll update without any problem on Azure.

If you want to add the multimedia enhancements back to the N version, you can install https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/49919 (1511) or https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/53356 (1607 anniversary edition).